# What factors influence the "system category"? e.g. "Empire Bastion"

Tags: stellaris

In Stellaris 2.0, the systems are given a specific category, like "Empire Colony" (base name), "Empire Bastion" (lots of defense platforms? border system?), "Naval Base" (home starbase of a fleet), "Mining Colony" (only has mining platforms), below the name of the system.

I've looked through the Stellaris Wiki but there's no mention of this feature, let alone the factors that influence them.

Comment: Well, Stellaris is still in active development, and things change (sometimes they change a LOT) so the wiki may not be updated yet. I don't remember system categories existing at all from last time I played.

Comment: If the subject interests you so much, go to the wiki & start a page on the subject.  Personally, I just see it as color text, and if I'm truly interested in the contents of the system, I open the system view.

Comment: @tjd How can I start a page on the subject if I don't fully understand it?

Comment: The same way Darth Xaim apparently did.  Play around a bit and find patterns.  The Scientific Method at work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The system category is decided by what is constructed in it- specifically starbases, colonies, and mining/research stations. As far as I can tell, it uses a prioritised list and picks the highest priority description that can apply.

The system description will be the first possibility from this list:

- **Empire Homeworld**: The homeworld of the founder species of the empire
- **Empire Capital**: The capital of the empire
- ***Starbase Title***: The title of the starbase in the system, based on its most built module. This is either:

  - **Trading Hub** (Trading Hubs),
  - **Empire Bastion** (Weapons),
  - **Shipyard System** (Shipyards), or
  - **Naval Base** (Anchorages).

  I haven't checked how priorities work in a tie, since I rarely mix modules.
- **Empire Colony**: The system contains one or more colonies but no starbase modules (either an outpost or a starbase with nothing built)
- **Research Outpost**: The system contains one or more research stations, and has at least as many research stations as mining stations.
- **Mining System**: The system contains two or more mining stations and has more mining stations than research stations.
- **Frontier Outpost**: None of the above.

Comment: There may be a few obscure ones (I want to see if megastructures add their own descriptor, for example) that I've missed. Also, is it possible to use nested bullet points on this site?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use nested bullet points. I made an edit to your answer which demonstrates it.

Answer (score 1):

So far I see,

- **Naval Base = Anchorage.**    Build lots of Anchorages
- **Trading Hub**                Build lots of Trading Hub
- **Shipyard System**            Build lots of Shipyards
- **Research Outpost**           System has more than average Research
- **Mining System**              System has more than average Resources
- **Frontier Outpost**           System has less than average everything
- **Empire Bastion**             System has more than average Weapons
- **Empire Colony**              System has Pop (whether Planet or Habitat)
- **Empire Homeworld**           Self-evident
- **Empire Capital** If you've moved your capital from your homeworld.

Anyone please update if I'm wrong